# Unable to chown although user exists

Tags: linux, rhel, chown

I am unable to "`chown`" to username from UID.

For example:

```
123456789 123456789 jdoe
--------------------------------------

chown jdoe:jdoe jdoe
```

I get:

> `chown:invalid jdoe 'jdoe:jdoe'`

but '`jdoe`' exists.

Comment: you are trying to chown folder or file or what?

Comment: i am trying to chown a home dir from UID to username.                           It's currently 123456789:123456789 and tyring to chown to jdoe:jdoe.

Comment: jww is correct; however, reading `man chown` could save you the trouble of asking again. `chown` has two arguments: the directory, and the user/group.

Answer (score 0):

this gonna change owner of `UID` directory to `jdoe`

```
cd ~
cd ..
sudo chown -R jdoe:jdoe UID/
```

Comment: I tried that.  Output was:   chown: invalid user: 'jdoe:jdoe' but jdoe does exist.

Comment: can you give me output of `id -u jdoe` ?

Comment: output: 123456789

Comment: give output of getent passwd | grep jdoe

Comment: your user have some problem,you can backup jdoe home folder and recreate it again

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem moving users from one system to another with different UID and GID. Linux used to allow users to have ids above 499. Now 999. Sigh

Anyway if you use numeric form in `chmod` you won't get the absurd error message.

```bash
cd /home
chmod -R 1003.1003 joe
```

This verified on Ubuntu 20

Comment: That cd line didn't format like I typed it. cd /home and chmod are on different lines, of course